# Send GCM Push Notification to android with custom sound

Tags: php, android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending GCM Push notification to Android app (built with hybrid php via cordova) from php server with following parameters options:

```
                'message' => $message,
                'image' => "www/icon/icon2.png",
                'title' => $title,
                'vibrate' => 1,
                'priority' => 1,
                'visibility'=> 1,
                'foreground'=> true,
                'no-cache' => 1,
                'force-start' => 1,
                'sound' => "res/raw/notify.mp3"
```

**"notify.mp3" is present in res/raw directory in app** (apk).

Notification comes to app successfully but specified sound does not rings, just vibration.

I have tried following but none worked:

> 'res/raw/notify.mp3'
>   'notify.mp3'
>   'android.resource:res/raw/notify.mp3'
>   'android.resource://R.raw.notify.mp3'

I have searched a-lot but could not came to solution to run custom sound notification.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to specify extension of file resides under res/raw folder. I Just put "notify.mp3" in res/raw folder and modified code as following:

```
'sound' => "notify"
```

It worked for me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the folder of the sound:

```
'sound' => "notify.mp3"
```

Comment: all I tried are:

'res/raw/notify.mp3' 
'notify.mp3' 
'android.resource:res/raw/notify.mp3'
'android.resource://R.raw.notify.mp3'

but none worked.